# Triggering button on windows form using a physical joystick button

Tags: c#, winforms, click, visual-studio-2019, joystick

Background:

Joystick - Razor Ruiji Master

Visual Studio 2019

Windows Form in C#

**I'm trying to figure out how to make a physical joystick button press, press a button on the windows form UI in Visual studio using C#.**

Code of Physical joystick:

```
private void joystickTimer_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            joystick.UpdateStatus();
            joystickButtons = joystick.buttons;

            if (joystick.Xaxis == 0)
                output.Text+="Left\n";

            if (joystick.Xaxis == 65534)
                output.Text+="Right\n";

            if (joystick.Yaxis == 0)
                output.Text+="Up\n";
            
            if (joystick.Yaxis == 65535)
                output.Text+="Down\n";

            

            for (int i = 0; i < joystickButtons.Length; i++)
            {
                // Assigning buttons
                if (joystickButtons[0] == true)
                    output.Text += "Cross\n";
                

                else if(joystickButtons[1] == true)
                    output.Text += "Circle\n";

                else if(joystickButtons[2] == true)
                    output.Text += "Square\n";


                else if (joystickButtons[3] == true)
                    output.Text += "Triangle\n";
                    Btn_Emergency_Stop_Click(sender,e); //Attempt at button press
                   //Btn_Emergency_Stop_Click.Click += joystickButtons[3];
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            joystickTimer.Enabled = false;
            connectToJoystick(joystick);
        }
    }
```

Virtual button to be pressed:

```
private void Btn_Emergency_Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bool showed = false;
        if (!showed)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Emergency stop pressed!");
            showed = true;
        }

    }
```

If there is any information I've missed out in providing please notify me, Thank You!

Comment: Is getting the button presses from the joystick working ok? Calling the button handler should be ok. Where is the code failing?

Comment: Yep, the joystick button press is working, I've managed to make it output the words circle, cross, triangle and square to a RichTextBox. I'm sort of confused as to where to go on from here. You mentioned button handler, I assume that should look into that.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the button is clicked? I assume Btn_Emergency_Stop_Click is the event handler for the button click event. Did you just leave out the contents of this function or is it actually empty like you've shown? This function should contain the code that runs when the button is pressed.

Comment: What I want when the physical joystick button is pressed is for Btn_Emergency_Stop_Click to also be pressed. As for the virtual button Btn_Emergency_Stop_Click, I don't have any plans other than to display a message box with text to show that it works. (I've updated the question to include the message box wen Btn_Emergency_Stop_Click is pressed.

Comment: That seems ok (except the message box will be shown every time). Can you add breakpoints and see if it's making it into Btn_Emergency_Stop_Click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to solve this, basically, I needed to add the call of the button's method right underneath the if statement. Otherwise, if you put the call of the button's method two lines below it loops infinitely.

```
private void joystickTimer_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            joystick.UpdateStatus();
            joystickButtons = joystick.buttons;

            if (joystick.Xaxis == 0)
                output.Text += "L-Left\n";

            if (joystick.Xaxis == 65535)
                output.Text += "L-Right\n";

            if (joystick.Yaxis == 0)
                output.Text += "L-Up\n";

            if (joystick.Yaxis == 65535)
                output.Text += "L-Down\n";
            
            for (int i = 0; i < joystickButtons.Length; i++)
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        if (joystickButtons[0] == true)
                            Btn_Manual_Mode_Click(null, null);
                            break;

                    case 1:
                        if (joystickButtons[1] == true)
                            Btn_Stop_Auto_Click(null, null);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        if (joystickButtons[2] == true)
                            Btn_Standby_Mode_Click(null, null);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        if (joystickButtons[3] == true)
                            Btn_Auto_Mode_Click(null, null);
                        break;


                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            joystickTimer.Enabled = false;
            connectToJoystick(joystick);
        }
    }
```